# jquery .bind or .change to populate span tag value from calendar onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a booking form where end users can reserve the date they wish, On occasion this can change right up to the payment page, If a date they previously tried to select becomes available they are notified and given the chance to change the date.

I need to be able to populate/change/bind to a span tag that already has text rendered when the dom loads, for example:

```
<span id="ReservationDate" name="ReservationDate">Your reservation date: 23/03/2016</span>
```

If they click to change the date a calendar provides the available dates and onclick selects the date with the following example attributes:

```
<td data-day="23" class="is-selected"><button class="pika-button" type="button">23</button></td>

<td data-day="24" class=""><button class="pika-button" type="button">24</button></td>
```

I need to be able to bind the date attribute for example: `data-day="24"` that they select to the span tag without having to change the span tag to an input field as this will break the css and page layout.

As a total newbie in jquery and javascript i would be very greatful if anyone can lend a helping hand on this, it will mean a lot and be very appreicated.

Thankyou.

Short update:

```
                    <div class="PaymentForm-ReservationDate">
                     <span id="ReservationDate" name="ReservationDate">Date: {{ $getResDate }}</span><br/>
                     <a href="" date-picker="" id="reservation-date">Change Date?</a>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var span = document.getElementById( 'ReservationDate' );

var updateDate = function(){
    span.innerHTML = 'Your reservation date: ' + this.dataset.day + span.innerHTML.slice( -8 );
};

var tds = document.getElementsByTagName( 'td' );
for( var i=0; i<tds.length; i++ )
    tds[i].onclick = updateDate;
```

Comment: Hi janje, unfortnetly i can not seem to get that to work, i would like to say thank you for taking the time to assist though its greatly appreicated, I have updated my question with the full div element and span tag to how the markup is structured, Im not sure why its not working, The date just does not change at all from when its first rendered. Hopefully we can get it resolved as its really getting to me now, spent hours trying to resolve this one slight thing.

Comment: @Blem19 I suppose the problem is somewhere else, as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qkc7ttw4/), the date does get changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solve your issue, but there is the code:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.pika-button', function(){
      var dataDay = $(this).parent('td').attr('data-day');
      $('span#ReservationDate').text('Your reservation date: ' + dataDay + '/03/2016')
    });
```

Comment: Unfortnently it doesnt, i would like to say thank you for taking the time to assist though its greatly appreicated, I have updated my question with the full div element and span tag to how the markup is structured, Im not sure why its not working, The date just does not change at all from when its first rendered :(

Comment: this {{ $getResDate }} is backend or some front-end template processor ?